# Why cant we draw a square like triangle?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I found the code in android documentation.

```
public class Square {

private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
private ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;

// number of coordinates per vertex in this array
static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
static float squareCoords[] = {
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   // top left
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
         0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f }; // top right

private short drawOrder[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 }; // order to draw vertices

public Square() {
    // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
    // (# of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
            squareCoords.length * 4);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(squareCoords);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    // initialize byte buffer for the draw list
    ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
    // (# of coordinate values * 2 bytes per short)
            drawOrder.length * 2);
    dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
    drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
    drawListBuffer.position(0);
}
```

}

why can't we write simply the following code to accomplish the task?

```
private short drawOrder[] = {0,1,2,3};
```

Is this written so only for performance reasons or is it the only way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL ES doesn't support quads as a native primitive type; only points, lines, and triangles.

Comment: You mean because of this GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);    that is here GLES20.GL_SQuare is not defined.

Comment: Correct. Triangles have the lovely property that they are always planar - makes them much easier to handle in GPU hardware ;P

Answer (score 2):

You can use `{0,1,2,3}` as the content of the index buffer. Instead of using `GL_TRIANGLES` as the primitive type, you'll have to specify `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` as the first argument of `glDrawElements()` instead.

Or, if you swap the last two indices to make it `{0,1,3,2}`, you can draw them with the more commonly used `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` primitive type.

Both `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` and `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` are used to draw sets of connected triangles.

In fact, if your indices form just a simple sequence, you don't need them at all. You can simply get rid of the whole `drawOrder` stuff, and draw your square with `glDrawArrays()` instead of `glDrawElements()`:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
```